# How to add git submodule and tag it to a release?

Tags: git, git-submodules

```
git clone my-new-repo-url
mkdir deps
cd deps
git submodule add -b 6.2.0 https://github.com/leethomason/tinyxml2.git
```

yields

```
fatal: 'origin/6.2.0' is not a commit and a branch '6.2.0' cannot be created from it
Unable to checkout submodule 'deps/tinyxml2'
```

does not populate .gitmodules, but creates a folder `.git/modules/deps/tinyxml2` and adds a repo in `deps/tinyxml2`

I thought I did this way before, and it would populate .gitmodules with

```
[submodule "deps/tinyxml2"]
    path = deps/tinyxml2
    url = https://github.com/leethomason/tinyxml2.git
    branch = 6.2.0
```

but it's not working now what's up?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A branch and a release tag are not the same thing. A branch may continue to be developed and change over time. Having the flag in .gitmodules `branch = something` means the submodule will track that branch when asked to update.

---

`git submodule add https://github.com/leethomason/tinyxml2.git` populates .gitmodules with

```
[submodule "deps/tinyxml2"]
path = deps/tinyxml2
url = https://github.com/leethomason/tinyxml2.git
```

Then manually checking out the desired tag in the submodule with

```
cd deps/tinyxml2
git checkout 6.2.0
```

Add/commit/push with

```
git commit -am "adding and commiting all in one command"
git push
```

Adds the submodule to the repo, and in the browser we can see

[image]

where `c1424ee4` is the specific commit where that release-tag was generated

Now doing a fresh clone into another folder

```
git clone my-new-repo-url
git submodule update --init --recursive
```

Has the submodule checked out at the same release tag 6.2.0 (commit `c1424ee4`)